# jQuery 1.4.2 IE8 error on page expected ')'

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I'm having an issue with IE8 (nothing new there). The error I'm getting is not making much sense as it does not occur on FF or Chrome. Here's the code:

```
function remComp(id, trade) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "functions/removePriceSurveyComparison.php",
                type: "POST",
                async: true,
                data: "id="+id,
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function(xmlData) {
                    if ($("success", xmlData).text() == "true") {
                        loadComps(trade);
                    }// TODO create error handler
                }
            });
        }
```

In this function it is complaining about the line where the success callback is defined. This function has not even been called yet though? But when it does get called, it works perfectly fine, although still creates new errors?

The function that is being called though is:

```
        function loadComps(trade) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "functions/loadPriceSurveyComparisons.php",
                type: "POST",
                async: true,
                data: "trade="+trade,
                cache: false,
                dataType: "html",
                success: function(comps) {
                    $("#current"+trade).html(comps);
                }
            });
        }
```

The second function is basically getting called 3 times when the page loads. Any advice?

Here is the complete script block as well:

```
        function remComp(id, trade) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "functions/removePriceSurveyComparison.php",
                type: "POST",
                async: true,
                data: "id="+id,
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function(xmlData) {
                    if ($("success", xmlData).text() == "true") {
                        loadComps(trade);
                    }// TODO create error handler
                }
            });
        }

        function addComp(trade, albId, compId) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "functions/addPriceSurveyComparison.php",
                type: "POST",
                async: true,
                data: "trade="+trade+"&albId="+albId+"&compId="+compId,
                cache: false,
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function(xmlData) {
                    if ($("success", xmlData).text() == "true") {
                        loadComps(trade);
                    }// TODO add an error handler
                }
            });
        }

        function updateComp(id, trade) {
            var albId = $("select#albProd"+id).val();
            var compId = $("select#compProd"+id).val();

            $.ajax({
                url: "functions/updatePriceSurveyComparison.php",
                type: "POST",
                async: true,
                data: "id="+id+"&albId="+albId+"&compId="+compId,
                cache: false,
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function(xmlData) {
                    if ($("success", xmlData).text() == "true") {
                        // reload table for this trade
                        loadComps(trade);
                    }// TODO create error handler
                }
            });
        }

        // function that loads all of the comparisons for a specific trade
        function loadComps(trade) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "functions/loadPriceSurveyComparisons.php",
                type: "POST",
                async: true,
                data: "trade="+trade,
                cache: false,
                dataType: "html",
                success: function(comps) {
                    $("#current"+trade).html(comps);
                }
            });
        }

        // define document.ready function
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // load all of the comparisons for each trade
            <?php
            foreach ($trades as $trade) {
                echo "loadComps(\"$trade\");\n";
                ?>
                $("#addComp<?php echo $trade; ?>").click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    addComp("<?php echo $trade; ?>", $("#albProd<?php echo $trade; ?>").val(), $("#compProd<?php echo $trade; ?>").val());
                });
                <?php
            }
            ?>
        });
```

Comment: That looks perfectly fine to me. And I've got my bracket-specs on.

Comment: Hehe, yeah, but IE8 is proving a headache and apparently having errors on a page that don't really do anything is not acceptable....

Comment: Any other scripts on the page?

Comment: Nothing wrong with that. There must be an error elsewhere. Have you tried running all your code through jslint?

Comment: Ok updated the post with the complete script block. In the $(document).ready block you'll notice some PHP, that just basically prints the loadComp function to be called for as many times there is a "trade".

I haven't tried jslint yet, will have a look now, thanks.

Comment: Ran my code through jslint. First it complained that loadComp is being called before its defined. Moved its definition to the top. Ran again through jslint. Got the following error:

Implied global: $ 4,12,18,25,33,41,49,50,52,60,69,72,74,77,79,82,84, document 69

Not sure what that means lol

Comment: OK, did some quick research on the jslint error. Not serious and I hope not related. Any other ideas what the **** IE  is complaining about?

Comment: So I'm assuming no one has any idea how to fix this issue? lol

Comment: Is it possible your `$trade` variable contains a double quote character?

Comment: Nope, no special characters there at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSLint's error message "Implied Global" means that there are variables defined that are missing the "var" definition... this is especially problematic for IE8. You need to go through and add "var" to the line numbers listed (yes, there are lots).

Are you using an Asset Packager? The order of how assets are listed in your asset packager could be at fault here.